# To crumple up a paper

Tags: idioms

Is "crease up a paper" an idiomatically correct expression for the action of taking a piece of paper in your hands and pressing it into a ball? The action you would do, for example, if rejecting something you have written on a paper, before throwing it into the trash can.

Are there other idiomatic expressions for the same thing, and when would they be used? Is there a word for the result of this action – the "ball" of paper?

**Edit:** The title now reflects the correct expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [CRUMPLE](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/crumpled%20paper) a piece of paper - [creasing](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/creasing%20paper) it is to prepare making a paper air plane or origami

However once you have crumpled the paper, it likely becomes creased by your action, but that is incidental.

Other expressions

*Wad up a piece of paper*

*Ball up a piece of paper*

The latter gave me this strange synonym on one dictionary:
[Gunch](http://www.diclib.com/cgi-bin/d1.cgi?l=en&base=amslang&page=showid&id=4394) - verb; to ball up a piece of paper; usually used in conjunction with crinkle
    *She gunched and crinckled the bills in total disgust.*
but I would not use it since it also appears on Urban Dictionary as something horrible and on hackers dictionary both with no reference to paper

Comment: Cookies crumble, paper crumples. A crumple is a crushed fold. Like a car in a crash.

Answer (score 4):

A crease is just a sharp fold. I'm not familiar with "crease up a paper" as you were using it.   "Crumple a piece of paper" or "Crumple up a piece of paper" are much more common.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, **crumple** is better than *crease* in this case.

Other possible phrases are:

*ball up*

*screw up* (into a ball)

*scrunch up*

all of which I would happily use and have heard others use many times.

Answer (score 1):

I would say *screw up* a piece of paper, but I can't find any source online that confirms this usage. Perhaps *screw up* is overworked anyway.